# run in edit mode when save is clicked

Tags: javascript, publishing-page

```
var inDesignMode = document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName].MSOLayout_InDesignMode.value;

if (inDesignMode == "1")
{
// page is in edit mode write code here

    var heading1 = document.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00');
    var heading2 = document.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl01');
    var heading3 = document.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl02');
    var heading4 = document.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl02_ctl00_ctl03');
    var arr2 = [heading1.checked,heading2.checked,heading3.checked,heading4.checked];
    sessionStorage.setItem('headings', arr2);

}
```

I have this code, which only runs when editing my sharepoint page. How can I make it so it only runs when I click save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the script in your .aspx page, and then attach it to your button.

```
document.getElementById("ID_of_save_button").onclick = myScript;
```